# Replace Entire Content of Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there a way to replace the ENTIRE contents of an iframe using Javascript (or Jquery)?

For example if my iframe had the following content...

```
blah outside of html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> my title </h1>
</body>
</html>
blah outside of html
```

..It could all be replaced by your script :)

The best that I've seen so far is this:

```
$(youriframe).contents().find('html').html('your content here');
```

but that still wouldn't replace the content outside of the html tags. We have an interesting scenario where we must assure that ALL the content is replaced.

OR a new iframe with fresh content is created and simply replaces the previous iframe.

Please no comments about the src attribute.

Comment: Is `theIframe.parentNode.replaceChild(theIframe, theNewIframe)` an option?

Comment: *Why* is changing the `src` attribute not an option? We can't really help unless we understand your requirements.

Comment: Hahaha I'm pretty sure my requirements were clear. Anyways, we're making a server request, generating some long running content on the server, returning it back to the client. The response data includes the content for the parent window AND the iframe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write elements into a child iframe using Javascript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997986/write-elements-into-a-child-iframe-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 25):

The code works fine in Chrome or FireFox, but in IE8, nothing will be showed or the scroll bar in iframe won't appear.

Tried this one:

```
var doc = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(iframeContent);
doc.close();
```

this works on my case, both ie8 and FF/chrome.

If i use Rachel's method, the iframe content will be like this in all browsers:

```
<iframe>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 20):

I'm guessing that you're not having problems with cross-site scripting in this instance... Have you had any luck using contentWindow? Something like this seems to work well enough for me:

```
iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_id');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open()
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(new_content_here);
```

Not my idea, found it here: [Write elements into a child iframe using Javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997986/write-elements-into-a-child-iframe-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: If you're going to do this more than once, you'll need to use iframe.contentWindow.document.close(), otherwise Firefox will ignore future writes. The close() method will also trigger the frame's load event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code:

```
$('#IframeID').contents().find("html").html(html);
```

Although this way you can work better in many of the cases, there will be more order:

```
$('#IframeID').contents().find("head").html(head);
$('#IframeID').contents().find("body").html(body);
```

So, you can play with `head` and `body` separately, and a bad change on body will not affect your head.

I tested on Chrome.

Comment: After a time, I can say the second form is the correct answer. I replace head for stylesheets and body separately. I used a HTML template with head and body separated by a string, and with a split() command I get it separated.

Answer (score -3):

have a similar scenario, where I am generating a new iFrame with content from a different domain each time the row of a table is clicked.

To do this, I use jQuery AJAX and PHP. PHP looks at my MySQL table and gets the URL of the iFrame I want to load; it generates the HTML for an iFrame, and I use jQuery AJAX to replace that content.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="xFrame">
    <iframe id="xFrameWindow" name="xFrameWindow" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

And my AJAX call looks like this:

```
function loadPage(record_id) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/ajax_handler.php",
        data: "action=makeIFrame&record_id=" + record_id,
        success: function(msg){
            $('.xFrame' ).html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

The code replaces the HTML of the div that contains the iFrame with a new iFrame.

Hope this (or something similar) works for you.

Comment: That replaces the entire iframe including the scr attribute. In this case, I need to replace the *content* of an iframe directly, from within the parent window, without refreshing the iframe