# How to replace entire contents of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784638/replace-entire-content-of-iframe) didn't receive any satisfactory answers, so I'm asking again.

I can get my iframe like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('preview');
var win = iframe.contentWindow;
var doc = win.document;
```

And write some initial HTML to it like this:

```
doc.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"></head><body>blah blah</body></html>');
```

And that works great, but now I want to replace the entire thing with some new content. How can I do that?

To be clear, by "entire thing" I mean the `<head>` too. I need to link some external JS and CSS there.

Preferably, this would also include the `<!DOCTYPE>`, but it's non-essential at this point.

Comment: @RobG: Actually, no. The two answers posted here are completely different than the ones posted there, and they actually work. Why did I expect something different? Because it's been half a year since that last question was posted and there's a new user base here, and because I can't effectively bump an old question.

Comment: @RobG: Also, Esailija posted some insightful tips that I didn't know and weren't present in the other answers either.

Comment: got your question confused with a very similar one posted about the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply remove the old iframe node from the DOM and create a new one containing the new contents.

Comment: Yes, theoretically I could replace the entire iframe, but wouldn't it be more efficient to replace just the iframe's document? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Setting `doc.documentElement.outerHTML` to something gives `message: "NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM Exception 7"`, so you can't replace the entire document but anything below `<html>` element is possible (`<head>` and `<body>`)

Comment: @Esailija: Good to know! With your help, I think I've got everything I need to know now! :) I believe this makes Darin's solution the most effective answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe using innerHTML should work:

```
doc.documentElement.innerHTML = "<script src='blah.js'></script><style></style>"
```

Comment: Ah...that explains why my attempts weren't working. Have to do it on the `documentElement`! That seems to work, but I can't set the `<!DOCTYPE>` with this method, can I? Basically this replaces the *contents* of `<html>` no?

Comment: the `<!DOCTYPE>` element itself isn't modifiable but the document has property `iframe.contentWindow.document.doctype` which has properties like `doc.doctype.systemId`. The properties are read-only so it is probably not recommended to try and change the doctype dynamically