# How can I change page which contents a radio frame without reload this frame again in Html or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have two pages:
**index.html** and **About.html**, and in each page i have a frame like dyhis:

```
<iframe src="https://www.myradio.com/cela-radio/" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

It is a radio frame, I want when user change page **index.html** to **about.html**, the radio dont cut sound and not reload again in the seconde page, So i can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Entire Content of Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784638/replace-entire-content-of-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

@Sylarman5 I believe you can use localStorage to verify if your dominion is open in other page. If have a value you not execute the radio in this page.