# Iframe content not showing

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe without src. This because the iframe only shows webpage content (from the src) when a user clicks a button (the src is then replaced by a webpage URL). That button is already working.
But when nobody clicks the button, the iframe has to show some simple default text instead of that webpage. In my example I have written the text line 'This text must be displayed by default.'. Why is the text not showing up?
I need to keep the onload javascript, because that is important for the functionality of the iframe.

```
<iframe src="" class="prodframe pc" style='bottom:0px;position:absolute;width:90%;height:73%;margin:0px auto;left:0;right:0;border:none;background:none transparent;' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' allowtransparency='true' onload='window.onmessage=function(e){var c=0;var o=document.getElementById("zoekframe");if(o.offsetParent){do{c += o.offsetTop;}while(o = o.offsetParent);};scrollTo(0,c);};' id=zoekframe>This text must be displayed by default.</iframe>
```

I have a fiddle on the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/mfhdwmya/

Comment: for clarity: the button that replaces the content is just background information, you don't have to do anything with that. Only concern is how to show that simple text line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is awfully similar to [Alternate text for iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252676/alternate-text-for-iframes)

The accepted solution for that one is:

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $("iframe").not(":has([src])").each(function () {

    var ifrm = this;

    ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;

    ifrm.document.open();
    ifrm.document.write($(this).attr("alt"));
    ifrm.document.close();

    });

});
</script>
```

I'd comment, but my reputation was not yet enough.