# jquery event as soon as iframe content changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which changes content of the iframe (for instance change the URL of the images). Currently, I bind a function to iFrame's `load`. Something like:

```
$('iframe#frame').load(function() { });
```

The problem is, when I run this and change the `src` attribute of the iframe, the function runs **after** all the elements are loaded and then changes it. I want to be able to run the code **as soon as the HTML content of the iFrame is loaded** to prevent the extra loading time. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  $.get('https://google.com', function(data){
      var doc = $frame[0].documentElement;
      doc.open();
      doc.write(data);
      doc.close();
      $frame.trigger('ijustchangedthesrc');
  }, 'HTML');
```

later

```
  $('iframe#frame').on('ijustchangedthesrc', function(){});
```

Give your iframe no src to start with.

Comment: Nope! Tried, doesn't work. It runs before the HTML is changed so I can't access the HTML inside the iframe.

Comment: It's easy, I just set the `src` of the iframe. `$frame.attr('src',  'https://google.com');`

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but the result is the same as `ready`. The event is fired up **before** the HTML is loaded from the server.

Comment: Ok I am getting a better idea of what you need. Try the above.

Comment: Awesome. As soon as I read the first line of your answer, I knew it's gonna work. For some reason I couldn't use the `$frame` jQuery variable and used the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997986/write-elements-into-a-child-iframe-using-javascript-or-jquery). In the end it worked perfectly.

Comment: Shweet. Glad to be of help.