# Cannot write content inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Scrape test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="beatles">
            <div>
                <iframe id="gozujinsama"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ifrm = document.getElementById('gozujinsama');
            var doc = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;
            doc.open();
            doc.write("<DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=\"http://google.com\"><img src=\"\"/></a></body></html>");
            doc.close();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I try is to simulate how various ad scripts write html content in iframes. But when I try to visit it then I get the following error from my javascript console:

> TypeError: doc.write is not a function

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach is:

```js
var ifrm = document.getElementById('gozujinsama');
var doc = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;

doc.open();
if(doc.write){
    doc.write("<DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=\"http://google.com\"><img src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/272px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png\"/></a></body></html>");
} else {
   doc.document.write("<DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=\"http://google.com\"><img src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/272px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png\"/></a></body></html>");
}

doc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the code wrong.

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('gozujinsama');
var doc = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;

doc.document.open();
doc.document.write("<DOCTYPE html><html><body><a href=\"http://google.com\"><img src=\"\"/></a></body></html>");
doc.document.close();
```

The `ifrm` object has a property of `document` which has the function `write`. In your code you tried to call the `open`, `write`, and `close` functions on a DOM reference.

[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997986/write-elements-into-a-child-iframe-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code based on your code.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MMRahman/e3fkrsek/)

Full working Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Scrape test</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="beatles">
        <div>
            <iframe id="gozujinsama"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('gozujinsama');
        var doc = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;
        doc.document.open();
        doc.document.write('<DOCTYPE html><body><a href=\"http://google.com\"><img src=\"\"/></a></body></html>');
        doc.document.close();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```